# what are the syntactic difference between qml and json?

Tags: json, qml

what are the syntactic difference between qml and json?
could one, with a few changes transform qml to json, or json to qml?

Comment: One is a standard for data interchange (JSON), the other is a modeling language. I think you're a bit confused due to syntax similarity, which comes from both being rooted in JS.

Comment: Hi Tim, I meant differences syntax-wise. Isn't it obvious? Qt's qml is for gui.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you noted that in your question. It reads like you are asking about the fundamental differences of the two. In other words, your question could lead people to think you are trying to compare an orange with a tree.

Comment: Thank you. Now that I re-read it, I didn't mention syntax. Sorry.  now changed the question

Comment: I think a better question is: Couldn't QML have been designed to work with JSON or BSON syntax instead of QML's own syntax? I don't see why that wouldn't be possible...

Comment: this is a good question - i can't understand why it was downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Read:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

You'll see the difference...

Bottom line there more differences then common